# Prevent Google Indexing my Pagination System

Tags: seo, search-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am wondering if there is a way to include in my robots.txt a line which stops Google from indexing any URL in my website, that contains specific text.

I have different sections, all of which contain different pages. I don't want Google to index page2, page3, etc, just the main page.

The URL structure I have is as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/section
http://www.domain.com/section/page/2
http://www.domain.com/section/article_name
```

Is there any way to put in my robots.txt file a way to NOT index any URL containing:

```
/page/
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: Googlebot  
Disallow: http://www.domain.com/section/*
```

or depending on your requirement:

```
User-agent: Googlebot 
Disallow: http://www.domain.com/section/page/*
```

Also you may use the [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) rather than the robots.txt file

Comment: The only problem I see is that articles take the URL www.domain.com/section/article_name, so disallowing * after section/ would disallow the articles, can I just disallow the URL if it has "/page" in it? Thanks for your help your answer is almost perfect!

Comment: @Cristian - Use Google's Webmaster Tools if you want more control.

Comment: @Ramhound I do use google webmaster, I can't find where I can do what I'm asking, could you provide a little guidance?

Comment: Using this, google only disapear page title in search result but page indexed and exist in search.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto GWT / Crawl / URL Parameters
2. Add Parameter:  page
3. Set to:  No URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use 
Disallow: /page

Comment: i think that only disallows URLs beginning with /page, which I don't have?